# Can you tell when a restored database was originally backup up?

Tags: sql-server

We backup nightly in production and restore in other environments.  Is there a way to tell in the restored environment when the backup was taken from the prime environment?

Comment: Have you tried looking *anywhere*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SSMS:-

- right-click your database.
- Choose Properties.

In the table in the middle of the dialog, is 'Last Database Backup' time and date.